# Elasticsearch showing received plaintext http traffic on an https channel in console

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to setup elasticsearch in my Windows system but when I am trying to run it its starting up and showing below reponse when I redirect to `http://localhost:9200`.

```
{
  "name" : "DESKTOP-L8UKCFI",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "z8IfZcFaQfSti3P4jhZxbg",
 "version" : {
   "number" : "8.1.0",
   "build_flavor" : "default",
   "build_type" : "zip",
   "build_hash" : "3700f7679f7d95e36da0b43762189bab189bc53a",
   "build_date" : "2022-03-03T14:20:00.690422633Z",
   "build_snapshot" : false,
   "lucene_version" : "9.0.0",
   "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
   "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
 }
```

But in console its showing something like this

```
[2022-03-16T11:26:12,307][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [DESKTOP- 
L8UKCFI] received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection 
Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9200, remoteAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:5996}


[2022-03-16T11:31:56,806][WARN ] 
[o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [DESKTOP-L8UKCFI] http 
client did not trust this server's certificate, closing connection 
Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9200, 
remoteAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:6215}
```

**elasticsearch.yml**

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
# address here to expose this node on the network:
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
# finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Allow wildcard deletion of indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: false

#----------------------- BEGIN SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -----------------------
#
# The following settings, TLS certificates, and keys have been automatically      
# generated to configure Elasticsearch security features on 16-03-2022 06:55:18
#
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: false

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: false

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: false
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

# Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: false
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
  truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
# Create a new cluster with the current node only
# Additional nodes can still join the cluster later
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["DESKTOP-L8UKCFI"]

# Allow HTTP API connections from localhost and local networks
# Connections are encrypted and require user authentication
http.host: [_local_, _site_]

# Allow other nodes to join the cluster from localhost and local networks
# Connections are encrypted and mutually authenticated
#transport.host: [_local_, _site_]

#----------------------- END SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -------------------------
```

What does it mean someone let me know.

Comment: How are you hitting the cluster? curl or otherwise?

Comment: Directly in a browser url bar. using `https://localhost:9200`

Comment: I saw tutorials on internet where it is working on `http` port but is not working for me its working on `https` port why so but when I modify security to false in `elasticsearch.yml`  then its wokring on `http` port.

Comment: can please post your elasticsearch.yml file configuration as well

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As of ES 8, SSL/TLS is ON by default for HTTP clients.

The WARN message says

```
http client did not trust this server's certificate
```

... which means that you need to tell your browser to trust the server certificate. it is self-signed by default, so that's probably the reason.

Or you can simply disable SSL in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration, that would also work.

Comment: I have made the ssl false in elasticsearch.yml file manually then its working on `http` port

Comment: That's also a solution, indeed.

Comment: Thats working fine. Now I am trying to run logstash  but its shutting down automatically as I have passed csv file in logstah.conf file as an input.

Comment: That's a different issue, this one is solved, you can then create a new thread.

Comment: Okk I am posting another question for that in a minute.

Comment: Can u please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71493412/unable-to-read-csv-file-in-logstash-as-its-shutting-down-on-its-own

Answer (score 50):

As @Val has already answered the question above just posting the code new users who wants to disable the SSL.

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: false

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: false

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: false
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

# Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: false
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
  truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
# Create a new cluster with the current node only
# Additional nodes can still join the cluster later
```

Comment: File to update is -> config/elasticsearch.yml

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much @infinteLearner

Answer (score 16):

Add the following to your environment variables:

`- xpack.security.enabled=false`

Full:

```
  b-elastic:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.4.0-arm64
    container_name: b-elastic
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms750m -Xmx750m
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    volumes:
      - ./:/project
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
```

Answer (score 11):

Another way is to simply run `elasticsearch` as

```
./elasticsearch -E xpack.security.enabled=false
```

It basically runs it with SSL disabled, allowing you to create HTTP connections with it.

Answer (score 2):

http client did not trust this server's certificate, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9200, remoteAddress=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:54479}

Simply means your browser is not trusting the software, so use https instead of http like https://localhost:9200/ it will work. I got this solution from internet

Comment: "I got this solution from internet" is a very reliable source reference.

Answer (score 2):

I run this code and it worked in windows, to do your /bin folder and run this in terminal

**elasticsearch -E xpack.security.enabled=false**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this through the environment variables when starting the docker container `docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e=xpack.security.enabled=false -e=xpack.ml.enabled=false -e=action.destructive_requires_name=false oais-registr y.oais.by/elasticsearch:8.6.2`